# How to give space in sentence in string with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, space

Here's i have an issue :
sentence : "12223233 sekamar berempat"

```html
$kamar = $_POST['kamarpilihan'];
 $kamarhuruf = preg_replace("/[^a-z]+""/", "", $kamar);
```

result:
sekamarberempat

expectation:
sekamar berempat

thank you

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^a-z]+/", " ", $kamar)`?  `trim(preg_replace("/[^a-z]+/", " ", $kamar))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all chars other than lowercase letters with a space and [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the string:

```php
$kamar = "12223233 sekamar berempat";
echo trim(preg_replace("/[^a-z]+/", " ", $kamar));
// => sekamar berempat
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/vJnvp).

Comment: pardon me, but how do i change the first character to capital? like "sekamar" to "Sekamar"?

Comment: @rayhanaulian Use [`ucfirst`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).